# How to unravel type dependency? (X uses undefined class Y)

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to implement simplistic fast memory management for my delegate type, but encountered circular dependency which I can't solve myself.

```
// Size of single bucket of delegates
static constexpr size_t _alloc_buffer_bucket_size = 128;

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args>
struct bucket;

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args>
class Delegate final : public IDelegate
{   
    . . .

    static void* operator new (size_t size)
    {
        auto bckt = _current_bucket; // gives compilation error here
    }
private:

    // Size of single bucket of delegates
    static constexpr size_t _alloc_buffer_bucket_size = 128;
    struct bucket
    {
        // stores currently occupied slots in bucket.
        size_t allocated_slots = 0;
        // when this bucket is filling with values, this 
        size_t current_slot = 0;
        std::array<Delegate<TFunc, Args...>, _alloc_buffer_bucket_size> slots = {};
    };
    // Vector of buckets.
    inline static std::vector<bucket*> _alloc_buffer = { new bucket(), };
    // This is a pointer to currently filling bucket. New delegates are added here
    // by delegate allocator.
    // When this bucket reaches _alloc_buffer_bucket_size of items, this pointer is
    // replaced with either newly allocated bucket or existing and empty bucket.
    inline static bucket* _current_bucket = &(_alloc_buffer[0]);
};
```

This gives me "`'Delegate<void (*)(void)>::bucket::slots' uses undefined class 'std::array<Delegate<void (*)(void)>,128>'`".
How can I break this circular dependency? I've tried using more pointers, moving bucket outside of Delegate scope, but this error remains.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to include `<array>`

Comment: Of course not, it's complaining about undefined delegate class. I've just put only essential code here, without includes and without full listing.

Comment: It complains about the class `std::array<Delegate<void (*)(void)>,128>` according to your question. Create a [mcve]

Comment: ok, here's full code, though it won't compile except on msvc and C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/jn7a9571a

Comment: You forgot the "minimal" part of MCVE.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bKGGqfb86

Comment: As I suspected, you did forget to include `<array>`

Comment: Ok, shame on me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the definition of the `bucket` struct outside of the scope of `Delegate` and assigning the `_alloc_buffer` and `_current_bucket` variables outside of the class scope, we can achieve compilation.  I was able to get it compiling as such:

```cpp
// Size of single bucket of delegates
static constexpr std::size_t _alloc_buffer_bucket_size = 128;

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args>
struct bucket;

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args>
class Delegate final : public IDelegate
{
public:
    Delegate() = default;
    static void* operator new (std::size_t size)
    {
        auto bckt = _current_bucket; // gives compilation error here
        return nullptr; // added to get rid of the error
    }
private:
    // Vector of buckets.
    static std::vector<bucket<TFunc, Args...>*> _alloc_buffer;
    // This is a pointer to currently filling bucket. New delegates are added here
    // by delegate allocator.
    // When this bucket reaches _alloc_buffer_bucket_size of items, this pointer is
    // replaced with either newly allocated bucket or existing and empty bucket.
    static bucket<TFunc, Args...>* _current_bucket;
};

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args>
struct bucket
{
    // stores currently occupied slots in bucket.
    std::size_t allocated_slots = 0;
    // when this bucket is filling with values, this 
    std::size_t current_slot = 0;
    std::array<Delegate<TFunc, Args...>, _alloc_buffer_bucket_size> slots = {};
};

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args> 
std::vector<bucket<TFunc, Args...>*> Delegate<TFunc, Args...>::_alloc_buffer = { new bucket<TFunc, Args...>(), };

template <typename TFunc, typename... Args> 
bucket<TFunc, Args...>* Delegate<TFunc, Args...>::_current_bucket = &(_alloc_buffer[0]);
```

By splitting up the declaration and definition of the static variables and by splitting out the bucket type, the `Delegate` class is defined by the time we go to actually use it.  See it in action here: https://godbolt.org/z/bx7hh1av9

Edit: Tested this minimum sample on MSVC and Clang.

Comment: Hm, this compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/eqa838Env
But not on my computer.
Upd.: nevermind, full code doesn't compiles either: https://godbolt.org/z/P6GPj46co

Comment: Ok, this is minimal, with same error and your suggestion: https://godbolt.org/z/bKGGqfb86

Comment: I've edited my sample.  With new context, the error has actually changed.  First, `std::array` requires the default constructor to be there, similar to a C-style array.  I've also added a fix for the `operator new` compile error.  Also, you don't have `#include <array>` in your sample, which caused the undefined class error.